# How to call different Flutter functions based on firebase querySnapshot result

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Using Flutter, I would like to search a Firebase collection (Collection X) to find out if a field  (Field Y) exists in any document in said collection. If the document containing the field exists I would like to perform a task ( Task A ), If a document containing the field doesn't exist I would like to perform a different task ( Task B).

Here's what I've tried:

```
final CollectionReference collectionXRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Collection X")

collectionXRef.where("Field Y", isEqualTo: Z)
                  .get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
                if (querySnapshot.docs.length > 0) {
                   Task A
                }
                else { Task B }
})
```

The issue I'm having is that no matter what I put in the If statement: `(querySnapshot.docs.length > 0)` The code keeps performing Task A

Here's what I've tried:

```
if (querySnapshot.docs.isEmpty)

if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) 

if (querySnapshot.docs.length > 0) 

if (querySnapshot.docs.length != 0)

if (querySnapshot.size > 0)

if (querySnapshot.size != 0)

if (querySnapshot.size == 0)

if (querySnapshot.size >= 1)
```

Desired behavior:  I want to perform "Task B" if there is no document In the collection that contains the searched field, however, the function always returns Task A, which work fine if there are results to display, but, If there aren't any results it shows a blank results page instead of performing Task B.

The collection "FbCollection1" has only 3 documents in it, 2 out of those 3 documents contain the field being searched for "Field Y". Nither the documents nor the searched field "Field Y" are nested.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that there are no results? Did you try to loop trough the resulting `docs`?

Comment: There are results, the problem is: I am trying to perform "Task B" if there is no document In the collection that contains the searched field, however, the function always returns Task A, which work fine if there are results to display, but, If their aren't any results it shows a blank results page instead of performing Task B.

Comment: Can you print out to the console the value of `querySnapshot.docs.length` and check what it shows when you expect an empty list.

Comment: I did as you requested, ``` querySnapshot.docs.length ``` == 0 both when i'm expecting and when I'm not expecting. I'm 100% sure I shouldn't be 0 when I'm expecting because the field exists in multiple documents.

Comment: Can you please include a snippet of your firebase structure. A screen shot of that collection would help clarify the question.

Comment: I'll describe it if you don't mind: The collection "FbCollection1" has only 3 documents in it, 2 out of those 3 documents contain the field being searched for "Field Y". Nither the documents nor the searched field "Field Y" are nested.

Comment: Well, that doesn't match the code in the question `.collection("Collection X")` so perhaps that's the issue? This is why we need to see structures in questions.

Comment: My apologies for the mix-up, "FbCollection1" == "Collection X", the problem has been figured out below, thank you for your time.

Comment: Glad it was solved! In the future, please include your structure because we would have spotted the issue right away if would could have seen what in your database (an Int instead of a string "")

Comment: Understood, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try it with this code:

```dart
collectionXRef.where("Field Y", isEqualTo: Z)
                  .get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {

                    bool hasData=false;

                    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((ds){
                      print('id: ${ds.id}');
                      hasData=true;
                    })

                if (hasData) {
                   Task A
                } else { Task B }
})
```

Pls also check if your filter is corect. Like the type of the value you search for.

Comment: I'm unable to run the code due to the following error: "The method 'forEach' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'."

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the code in the answer. Can you pls try it again.

Comment: I've tried it out, however, I only get Task B now when I'm expecting results and when I'm not expecting results.

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you tell me what you see when you expect data and what you see when you expect no data. When you have that you should see the IDs of the collection you get and if you don't expect data there shouldn't be anything printed out.

Comment: The updated code isn't working either. Dose it work on your end?

Comment: What do you mean with doesn't work? Do you get any error or does it not behave as you expect it to?

Comment: My apologies, I mean only Task B is still being performed.

Comment: Can you pls tell me what is getting logen when you try both of the versions?

Comment: Nothing gets printed out with this ``` print('id: ${ds.id}'); ``` All that happens is Task B. What are you getting on your end?

Comment: Can you share with me the code you use and a screenshot of your database of the collection you try to read there.

Comment: The problem was that I was searching for a string, however, the field was an int, ```collectionXRef.where("Field Y", isEqualTo: int.parse(Z))``` works, thank you for your time, please update your answer and I'll accept it.